# c++ Multithreading with std library: slower than expected

Tags: c++, multithreading

I tried to play with the std library ,in particular the thread one.
The idea is to fill a matrix with and without multithreading. I have 8 cores.

```
void fillMatrix(int ID, std::vector<std::vector<double>> & lMatrix,int inThread){

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i){
        if (i % inThread == ID){
            for (int j = 0; j < 10000; ++j){
                lMatrix[i][j] = 123456.0;
            }
        }
    }

}


void testMT(int inThread){

    std::vector<std::thread> lPool;
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> lMatrix(10000, std::vector<double>(10000));

    for (int i = 0; i < inThread; ++i){
        lPool.push_back(std::thread(std::bind(&fillMatrix,i, lMatrix,inThread)));
    }

    for (std::thread & t : lPool){
        t.join();
    }
}
```

The main code :

```
int main(){
    const clock_t begin_time1 = clock();
    testMT(1);
    std::cout << float(clock() - begin_time1) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
}
```

testMT(1) takes 2.1 seconds to run, while testMT(8) takes 7.032 seconds.

Any idea ? 
Thanks.

Comment: My guess is branch prediction failure. What happens if you eliminate the `if` by having the outer loop start at `ID` and increment by `inThread`?

Comment: So you are measuing the total CPU-time, which will be greater in eight threads than one.

Comment: You compare 1 call of fillingl matrix vs 8 calls. Why do you decide that 8 calls must be faster than 1?

Comment: Multithreading only helps if you're doing CPU intensive calculations, not memory operations. I wouldn't expect anything but a slowdown here.

Comment: False Sharing and Branch Prediction?

Comment: I do not expect the if statement to triple the time computation .Yes I measure the total time , you can disregard the clock, all I can tell is that the process is much slower with more threads. I am just playing with the library, no application yet

Comment: This whole thing is pointless since your program has undefined behavior if it was actually passed to bind correctly.  If you have more than one thread and at least one is a writer to shared data then you must provide synchronization.  You do not so it is UB.

Comment: Also it may interest you to know that you that your code does not run as expected. After the threads run, you'll notice that none of the elements are set to `123456.0`. This is because `std::bind` *copies* the vector into itself that's then sent to the thread. You need to use `std::ref(lMatrix)` in the bind call for it to work properly

Comment: Thanks vu1p3n0x!!! It was the reason ! Now it is much faster . You can write an answer

Comment: The term `STL` only properly refers to the *containers*, *iterators* and *algorithms*, not the entire Standard Library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code does not run as you want it to. After the threads run, you'll notice that none of the elements of `lMatrix` are set to `123456.0`. This is because `std::bind` copies the vector into itself that's then sent to the thread. You need to use `std::ref(lMatrix)` in the bind call for it to work properly and use the same matrix.

Change

```
std::bind(&fillMatrix,i, lMatrix,inThread)
```

to

```
std::bind(&fillMatrix, i, std::ref(lMatrix), inThread)
```

A significant portion of your increased execution time was therefore probably caused by the copy overhead; being 10000 x 10000 allocations and copies being made per thread launch (and then the deallocations afterwards).

Comment: @FredLarson I agree, though because it was running on OP's machine in 2-7s while on mine ran at 12-18ms (and his comment says this fix "made it much faster"), I wonder if the 850MB of memory used was more taxing than expected.

Comment: Oops, I had a bug in my test. The 8-threaded version is still 3 times slower than the single thread version.

Answer (score 5):

You have a very bad **if** that slows it down.

in the case of 1 thread it is always true, but in the case of 8 threads it is true then false false... true. Branch prediction fails here.

It is much better to split/divide the first for loop to each thread. Like thread 1 does the first 1/8th of the matrix, thread 2 does the second 1/8th and so on.

Something like:

```
for(int i = 10000*ID/inThread; i< 10000*(ID+1)/inThread; ++i)
```

in the case of ID=0 the loop will go from 0 to 2500, ID=1 will go from 2500 to 5000, and so on.

Comment: Yes , it is as Fred Larson said, there is a more efficient way to do that. Yet, I want to stick to my implementation , and understand why the time computation is tripled .Thanks.

Comment: @Canardini Out of curiosity, can you time this implementation against yours? I doubt branch prediction in the outer loop or cache misses could have such an impact in this case. Maybe there is something else at play yet...

Answer (score 4):

Your threads are all modifying the same object in nearby memory locations. That means ownership of the memory has to constantly ping pong from thread to thread.

This is not a sensible use of threads. If you hope to Preserve performance when numerous threads are all going to tightly spin around manipulating the same object concurrently, expertise is needed to handle things like false sharing.

Comment: The chunks of memory each thread writes in the inner loop are 80kb big. Way beyond any cache line size.

Comment: True, but the threads do nothing but modify those blocks and each block can overlap both the preceding and the following block on a cache line. Essentially, the thread do nothing but fill memory with static data. It's hard to see how multiple threads would speed that up anyway -- one thread can saturate the memory.

Answer (score 0):

In a way, this is a very important question.

- Multithreaded code is slower than single threaded code, always! (Best case, you still have to pay the cost of starting and stopping the threads)
- Concurrency makes things faster (sometimes).

Your goal is to have the gains from concurrency outweigh the cost of using threads -- and have the benefits be so significant that it "pays for" the added complexity of the code.  This example does not reach that goal.